# Can a LLC company with citizen(s)/resident(s) of the US and non-citizen/non-resident board members be filed for tax as a S-Corp?

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company, s-corporation

If there is a startup consists of citizen/resident and international(non-citizen/non-resident) students in the US who they want to create a company and get funding from investors, can they using S-Corp tax advantages for their LLC or is there any option like a S-Corp for reducing their tax or not?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica: for Federal tax [LLC is passthrough _by default_ but can _elect_ S-corp (if eligible) or C-corp treatment](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/llc-filing-as-a-corporation-or-partnership). But [S-corp rules don't allow nonresident alien owners/holders](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/s-corporations). Also note alien students generally aren't authorized to work (for pay) other than OPT arranged by the school (that's immigration rather than tax).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: Thank you, but the work would be unpaid and the important thing is holding a share of the company for him. So you mean there is no option for such startup to use advantage of S-Corp taxation? Can't citizen members treat their profit as S-Corp and non-citizen/residents as usual LLC?

Or there is no other same/similar option for such company at all?

Answer (score 1):

An LLC with two members can be taxed as a partnership, A C-corp or an S-corp.  Whatever you choose, it applies to the LLC as a whole so the different members cannot choose different taxation.

Pass-through taxation is pretty good because it avoids double taxation (both corporate and personal).  That is probably a better option than C-corp but you'll need an accountant to go through the details.  As noted in the comment, you can't do S-corp.

Answer (score 0):

An S-Corp cannot have non-resident shareholders. So no, if your LLC includes non-residents it cannot elect to be treated as an S-Corp.

To be treated as an S-Corp, a disregarded entity must satisfy all the requirements of eligibility under Sub-Chapter S, excluding incorporation.

See [26 CFR 301.7701-3](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/26/301.7701-3), [IRC Sec 1361](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/1361), and [IRC Sec 1362](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/1362).

The S election applies to the entity, not to the individual shareholders.